# ATL ActiveX DLL loaded twice as mapping type image & data

Tags: c++, com, activex, atl

I made simple atl control (activex) using vs2008 and loaded it on IE11.
and I could see that the process explorer shows two instances of that dll loaded from the same location.
difference between them is mapping type (image & data).
all the other ActiveX dll is loaded once, except mine.

does anybody know why?
can I make my AX same to other one?

sorry for my poor english, and any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the DLL is first loaded it will most likely show up as with 'Image' in Process Explorer's Mapping column, so that the code from your DLL can be executed.

If at some later point a resource from your DLL is required then it may show up a second time in the list but this time with 'Data' in the Mapping column, e.g. if the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag is used to [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx)